# Unable to pip install google-colab: Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to pip install google-colab, but get the following message:

´´´
Getting requirements to build wheel ... done

Installing backend dependencies ... done

Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> [4 lines of output]

```
  <string>:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html

  error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)

      pytz >= 2011k

           ~~~~~~~^

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.

╰─> See above for output.
´´´

I'm running this on Windows 11.
Version of python: 3.11.7
Version of pip: 23.3.2

I updated pip, wheel and setuptools. Didn't help.

I thought of changing the syntax in pyproject.toml by adding a semicolon, but I do not seem to find `pytz >= 2011k` anywhere in the file.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

The [stable release of google-colab](https://pypi.org/project/google-colab/) currently supports Python 2.7, 3.5 and 3.6. There's no support for your python: 3.11.7.

If you want to use this package, install a supported version perhaps python 3.6, and create a python 3.6 virtual environment for your project. Then you can `pip install google-colab` in that environment.